# Explode and leave delimiter

Tags: php

This is my function:

```
$words = explode('. ',$desc);
        $out = '';
        foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
            $out .= $value;
            $rand = rand(0, 4);
            if ($rand == 2) {
                $out .= "\n";
            } else {
                $out .= ' ';
            }
        }
```

In short it's inserting new lines after random dots, but in this case dots are removed.

How could I do `explode('. ',$desc)`, and leave dots in where they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them back in when you concatenate.

```
$words = explode('. ',$desc);
$out = '';
foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
    $out .= $value.'.';
    $rand = mt_rand(0, 4);
    if ($rand == 2) {
        $out .= "\n";
    } else {
        $out .= ' ';
    }
}
```

You should also use `mt_rand()`, it is a much better version of `rand()` unless you like *not really random* results.

Answer (score 0):

Positive look behind without regex subject.

```
$words = preg_split('/(?<=\.)(?!\s*$)/', $desc);
```

Split at any non-character with a `dot` behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
$words = explode('. ',$desc);

            $out = '';
            foreach ($words as $key => $value) {

                $out .= $value;
                $rand = rand(0, 4);
                if ($rand == 2) {
                   $out .= "<br>";
                } else {
                   $out .= ' ';
                }
            }
```